# How to get mouse button with node.on(Node.EventType.TOUCH_START) in CC 3.8?

Tags: game-development, cocoscreator

I am developing a game in Cocos Creator 3.8.2 in which the user clicks their mouse and a different command is run for clicking different mouse buttons. I've searched far and wide across the Internet and while I have found how to get which mouse button is pressed by using `AddEventListener()`, I cannot figure out how to get which mouse button is pressed with `node.on(Node.EventType.TOUCH_START, (event) =>{})`.

I tried running `console.log(event.getButton)` and `console.log(event.button)`, but all they return is `undefined`. At this point I am considering just using AddEventListener(). Does anyone know how to get which mouse button is pressed when a `TOUCH_START` event happens in Cocos Creator 3.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/engine/event/event-input.html#how-to-define-the-input-events), There's MOUSE_DOWN for the mouse click.

And the code would be something like this.

```js
node.on(Node.EventType.MOUSE_DOWN, (event) => {
    if (event.getButton() === EventMouse.BUTTON_LEFT) {
        // Left mouse button clicked
        console.log("Left mouse button clicked");
    } else if (event.getButton() === EventMouse.BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        // Right mouse button clicked
        console.log("Right mouse button clicked");
    } else if (event.getButton() === EventMouse.BUTTON_MIDDLE) {
        // Middle mouse button clicked
        console.log("Middle mouse button clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I was using the wrong event :( This will help me a ton!